# hive how to increment the values specific to condition?

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive

i have table like below:

```
itm    numbr
1        2
11       21
NULL     31
12       41
NULL     51
13       61
```

i want to output with itm,numbr and with extra column as mentioned below:

```
   itm      numbr    incr
    1        2        1
    11       21       1
    NULL     31       2
    12       41       2
    NULL     51       3
    13       61       3
```

the incr should increase its value only when ITM is equal to NULL else it should display the same value as previous value.

1.
i have tried with row_sequence

```
select itm,numbr,row_sequence() as incr from tablename;
```

but it displays 1,2,3,4,5,6.

2.
then i have tried with

```
select itm,numbr,case when itm=NULL then row_sequence()+1 else row_sequence() end as incr from table;
```

it throws error "FAILED: RuntimeException org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: Stateful expressions cannot be used inside of CASE".

please advice me. tia.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Untested but analytical function should help you, as value of the `incr` column depends on the values of other rows:

```
WITH tmpincr as (
  SELECT 
      itm
    , nmbr
    -- get in tmpincr 1 for NULL, 0 for not null
    , if(isnull(itm), 1, 0) as tmpincr
   FROM tablename
)
SELECT 
    itm
  , nmbr
  -- get the sum of tmpincr for all rows before current one when ordered by itm
  , SUM(tmpincr) OVER (
      ORDER BY nmbr
      ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW
    ) as incr
  FROM tmpincr
  ORDER BY nmbr
;
```

Comment: thanks @Guillaume. i am getting the results as NULL    202     1, 
NULL    204     2,
100     200     2,
101     201     2,
103     203     2,
105     205     2, but i do not want to order by the itm column.

Comment: Looks pretty close! I did forget to add an ORDER BY (answer updated, now ordering by nmbr). As you count the NULL coming in a specific order, one order clause is definitely required.

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE table_name
SET    incr = Coalesce(itm, 0) + 1
```

I haven't tried this solution but this adds 1 if is null otherwise increment number.
Modify it to fit  your needs =)