# Hive/ MySQL - Need help to increment consecutive 1's in the input column

Tags: mysql, hiveql

Need help in the below input column, for which I need the expected output column data. I need to increment the output column wherever I have consecutive 1's in the input column.

```
ID   Input_column          Expected Output Column     date_start   date_end
 1A       0                      0                      ts1            ts2
 1A       1                      0                      ts4            ts6 
 2B       0                      0                      ts7            ts9
 2B       1                      1                      ...            ...
 2B       1                      1                      ...            ...
 2B       0                      0                      ...            ...
 2B       0                      0                      ...            ...
 2B       1                      2                      ...            ...
 2B       1                      2                      ts11           ts15
 2B       1                      2                      ts20           ts22 
 2B       0                      0                      ...            ... 
 3C       0                      0                      ...            ... 
 3C       1                      3                      ...            ...
 3C       1                      3                      ...            ...  
 3C       1                      3
 3C       0                      0
 3C       1                      4
 3C       1                      4
 3C       0                      0
 3C       0                      0                      ts50            ts53
 3C       1                      0                      tsxx            tsyy
 3C       0                      0                      tsyy            tsnn
```

I tried the below answers, but it didn't worked out as expected.

1) [hive how to increment the values specific to condition?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46904255/hive-how-to-increment-the-values-specific-to-condition)

2) [Hive query generating identifiers for a sequence of row matching a condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30600543/hive-query-generating-identifiers-for-a-sequence-of-row-matching-a-condition)

Could someone help me in resolving this problem?

Comment: specify mysql version?

Comment: @vishal: I'm comfortable with any version, I mainly need the query to resolve this problem.

Comment: ordered by what? There is nothing which guarantees this order of data.

Comment: do you want query format of store procedure will be fined?

Comment: @leftjoin: Im not looking here to order by the output data. As specified in the problem, I need to increment or say iterate the output data wherever I have consecutive 1's in the input column

Comment: @vishal: query format would be much helpful, but yes I'm fine with stored procedure too.

Comment: How is it possible for someone to reproduce this order of your column? "consecutive" implies the data is ordered

Comment: @leftjoin: okay, but I have specified my problem as consecutive 1's in the input_column (both in the title as well as in the description) not as consecutive numbers. This is the problem I'm into now, can you please let me know what more information would be helpful to you? Or are you saying this may not be possible using sql?

Comment: Add some column defining the order of rows. Say ID or date. Without this the problem is not solvable at all. Consecutive 1's is when previous or next value is the same. And finding previous or next (using LAG or LEAD) requires ordering rule.

Comment: @leftjoin: I got your point and understood the mistake done by me. Now I have updated the data again, can you please check and also let me know if this information is sufficient enough, thanks for the help so far.Order by both ID or dates are fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pure SQL solution, using windowing functions, no joins,  tested on Hive with your data example:

```
with your_table as --use your table instead of this CTE
( 
select stack(23,
  1 , 0,        
  2 , 1,        
  3 , 0,        
  4 , 1,        
  5 , 1,        
  6 , 0,        
  7 , 0,        
  8 , 1,        
  9 , 1,        
  10, 1,        
  11, 0,        
  12, 0,        
  13, 1,        
  14, 1,        
  15, 1,        
  16, 1,        
  17, 0,        
  18, 1,        
  19, 1,        
  20, 0,        
  21, 0,        
  22, 1,        
  23, 0
) as ( ID ,Input_column  )  
) --use your table instead of this CTE

select s.id, s.input_column, 
       case when grp_id is null then 0 
            else dense_rank() over (partition by (grp_id is null) order by grp_id) 
         end as output_column
       from

(
select s.id, s.input_column, 
       case when same_group_flag then   --distribute same grp_id across same group
       max(grp_id) over(order by id rows between unbounded preceding and current row ) 
       end as grp_id
from
(
select s.id, s.input_column , 
       case when input_column=1 and (prev_value!=1 or prev_value is null) and next_value=1 then id end as grp_id,
       input_column=1 and (prev_value=1 or next_value=1)                                               as same_group_flag

       from
(       
select id, input_column, 
       lead(input_column) over(order by id) next_value,
       lag(input_column) over(order by id) prev_value
  from your_table
)s
)s
)s
order by id;
```

Result:

```
id  input_column  output_column
1       0       0
2       1       0
3       0       0
4       1       1
5       1       1
6       0       0
7       0       0
8       1       2
9       1       2
10      1       2
11      0       0
12      0       0
13      1       3
14      1       3
15      1       3
16      1       3
17      0       0
18      1       4
19      1       4
20      0       0
21      0       0
22      1       0
23      0       0
Time taken: 226.407 seconds, Fetched: 23 row(s)
```

The result is exactly as expected. Also have a look at the very similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55336802/2700344

Comment: Thank you so much for the help, this pretty much works close for my case. 
Though I edited the ID as it is not primary key after which you may not have noted, which is my fault where I should've given correct data at first.  
Can you please also confirm whether the same works for the now edited ID column (which has both int and char) in the description, so we cannot use max over this ID. please advice, thanks again!

Comment: Hi, in this case I would prefer (partition by ID order by date_start), kindly let me know if more information is needed, thank you!

Comment: @Naresh_17  Please create another question if you have already changed requirements instead of constantly editing initial one after the solution was implemented. Someone else may answer it. Constant editing question is simply wasting of answerers time. Look, this is not free coding service after all. Please read this: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/309237/2700344 And about your last question: You just need some sortable column which determines the order of your 1's and this solution will work. Replace ID in the query with another column or combination. Test and debug it yourself please.

Comment: Apologies as I'm still new to this global platform, I was also thinking on the whole thing you said, I understand the responsibilities to use this, thanks for the details. Yes, I'm using the other combination to try it. Hope it will work, thanks again!

Comment: @Naresh_17 I have checked, it does not work after changing IDs. The problem is not in chars. The problem is that your new ID column does not determine initial dataset order any more. For example why 3C,0 is before 3C,1? This was in my initial question, see comments. Ordered by what? If now it is timestamps, then use timestamps instead, ID's are not suitable for this purpose any more. Try replacing ID w timestamp. Hope you got the idea.

Comment: Hi, yes, I'm still trying to work out. Just trying to sort this out :- case when input_column=1 and (prev_value!=1 or prev_value is null) and next_value=1 then id end as grp_id. instead of ID, im trying whether I could implement input_column by itself, but then, I'm not sure enough here, since this seems to be a near perfect solution, I'm trying this idea of yours

Comment: @First of all you need some sortable column instead if ID. onwhich and only on which the order of input column depends. then LEAD, LAG and other windowing functions depending on order will become deterministic

Answer (score 0):

here is one way to solve this issue but table should have primary key required.
**you have to use mysql 8.0 for this**

```
delimiter $$
drop procedure if exists test2 $$
create procedure test2()
begin
declare v_count int default 1 ;
declare v_loop int default 1 ;
declare v_i int;
declare v_j int;
declare v_id int;
declare work cursor for select sr_no,lead(sr_no,1)over(order by id) as sr_no2,id  from tmp;

 SET @row_number:=0;
 SET @db_names:='';
 drop temporary table if exists tmp;
 create TEMPORARY table tmp  as 
select id,sr_no from 
(select id,
@row_number:= CASE WHEN (value1 and value2 =1) or @db_name=1  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS sr_no ,
@db_name:=  (CASE WHEN (value1 and value2 =1)  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
from 
(SELECT t2.id, t2.value1 as value2,t1.value1
FROM t4 t1
inner join t4 t2
on (t1.id = t2.id+1))A)d;


 OPEN work;
 work: LOOP 
 FETCH work INTO v_i,v_j,v_id;

 if ((v_i and v_j = 1) or v_i=1  ) then 
    SET v_loop=v_loop+1;
     if (v_loop > 0)then
       update tmp  SET sr_no= v_count   where id=v_id;
    end if;
 else 
     if(v_loop > 1)then
        SET v_count=v_count+1;
        SET v_loop =0;
     else 
        SET v_loop =0;
     end if ;  
 end if;


 END LOOP work;

 CLOSE work;


end $$
delimiter $$
```

run this sp and then just use

```
select * from tmp for your output
```

Comment: thank you vishal, though logically this could work, I still prefer the pure SQL solution instead of stored procedure, that is why I have chosen the other answer for my case. Otherwise, I see this logic would work as well!